# Laravel Slug Exist

Tags: php, laravel, slug

I want to create slug for blog categories. I do it like this;

```
Str::slug($request->title)
```

But I have to check if slug exist. If exist, I want to do like this;

```
// For example title is test. Slug must be test.
// But if slug exist I want to do it test1
if(count(blog_tags::where('slug',$slug)->get()) > 0){
     $slug = $slug . '1';
}
// But test1 too can be exist. So I have to test it.
```

If I test it again and again, system will be slow. What should I do?

Comment: Don't allow duplicates? Or, instead of appending `1`, append `blog_tags::where('slug',$slug)->count() + 1`. Also, you can do `$slug .= ...` instead of `$slug = $slug . ...`

Comment: @TimLewis I do this count thing. But I can't solve my problem. When I write just **test** as title, slug is being **test1**, but if I again write **test**, it's being **test1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following function in your controller class to check ending number in slug

```
protected function countEndingDigits($string)
{
    $tailing_number_digits =  0;
    $i = 0;
    $from_end = -1;
    while ($i < strlen($string)) :
      if (is_numeric(substr($string, $from_end - $i, 1))) :
        $tailing_number_digits++;
      else :
        // End our while if we don't find a number anymore
        break;
      endif;
      $i++;
    endwhile;
    return $tailing_number_digits;
}
```

Add the following function in your controller class to check slug already exists or not

```
protected function checkSlug($slug) {

if(blog_tags::where('slug',$slug)->count() > 0){
 $numIn = $this->countEndingDigits($slug);
 if ($numInUN > 0) {
          $base_portion = substr($slug, 0, -$numInUN);
          $digits_portion = abs(substr($slug, -$numInUN));
  } else {
          $base_portion = $slug . "-";
          $digits_portion = 0;
  }

  $slug = $base_portion . intval($digits_portion + 1);
  $slug = $this->checkSlug($slug)
}

return $slug
}
```

Now you will get a unique incremental slug

```
$slug = $this->checkSlug(Str::slug(string));
```